# Delete items from database with more than x days in CodeIgniter/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Can anyone tell me how to delete items from a table with more than 5 days in `CodeIgniter` please? I searched here and on google and can't find anything that works.

EDIT:

My table in database looks like this:

```
| ID| Name | CreationDate |

| 1 | Test | 01-12-2014   |

| 2 | Test2| 01-11-2014   |
```

and so on, I hope you understand me.

Comment: How dos your database look? if you only have 5 rows with dates you could do a if row1 not 0 and row2 not 0 for and row3 not 0 and row4 not 0 and row 5 not 0

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**

1. Get the current date
2. Calculate the date 5 days ago
3. Delete the items from the database where the `CreationDate` is less than (older than) 5 days

**Code:**

```
  $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
  $date = strtotime($date);
  $min_date = strtotime("-5 day", $date);
  $this->db->where("CreationDate < '$min_date'", NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: don't just post the answer. add a little bit of useful information too.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of CreationDate? What do you mean by `more than 5 days`?

If you mean you want to delete items where CreationDate is **older** than 5 days, and CreationDate type is string (**varchar**), you could use this:

`$this->db->query("DELETE FROM MyTable where STR_TO_DATE(CreationDate, '%d-%m-%Y') < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)";`

But if CreationDate type is **mysql date**, then simply use:

`$this->db->query("DELETE FROM MyTable where CreationDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)";`